# macOS photo album picker

Tags: macos, photos, picker

I've been able to search for iOS API documentation for accessing the Photos app (i.e. PHPhotoLibrary) but nothing for macOS. I'm trying to figure out whether there is an existing photo album picker similar to the one used in System Preferences for the Screen Saver (Preferences -> Desktop & Screen Saver -> Screen Saver -> Source -> Photo Library ...) I don't want something that selects individual photos, I want to be able to select album names. Just wondering if something like this exists already or if I have to write my own.

Also, is there any way to filter Xcode's Documentation and API Reference to just show macOS (or iOS) relevent items?

Thanks for any help or guidance.
Don

Answer (score 0):

Starting with macOS Big Sur, there's a [new Photos picker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phpickerviewcontroller) that achieves selection by album name, but only in a Mac Catalyst app.